# assign signal handler by pid

Tags: c++, linux, signals, posix

If I know a pid of a certain process that doesn't run the code(say firefox)
how do I assign a signal handler(say SIGINT) to it?

I have now :

```
    pid = fork();
    printf("forked and my pid is %d\n",pid);
    //check for errors
    if (pid<0){         
        printf("Error: invoking fork to start ss has failed, Exiting\n ");
        exit(1);
    }
    //the child process runs the gulp
    if (pid==0){
        printf("STARTING THE FIREFOX\n");           
                    //calling signal(somehandler,SIGINT); here will bind the child, which is replaced by the firefox new process,hence won't invoke the "somehandler"
        if (execv(args[0],args)<0){
            perror("Error: running s with execvp has failed, Exiting\n");
        }
                    //invoking signal(somehandler,SIGINT); will obviously not do anything
        printf("IVE BEEN KILLED\n");            
    }
    //dad is here
    printf("DAD IS GOING TO KILL\n");
    if (pid>0){
        sleep(6);
                    //how do I bind a handler to that signal????
        kill(get_pidof(string("firefox")),SIGINT);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only establish a signal handler **from within** the process. Put another way, you can't make firefox call your signal handler when it gets a SIGINT.

---

#### EDIT

As you noticed, indeed signal handlers are not kept after an exec - the image of the process is replaced so it wouldn't make sense. So, like I said before: you can't make `firefox` call your handler even if you control its parent.

> I need my program to run another program(say firefox), and to know
>   when the firefox died or crashed

In that case you want to establish a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`: your process will jump to it when the child dies.

Comment: Ok..so if I fork , and make the child process execv  another process, I can't bind the child process , because if I do the signal before the execv, the signal handler will not be called when the exec ends, because its no longer the child process, and I can't call the signal handler after the execv (for obvious reasons)..so do I do it?

Comment: @user1432779 I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you rephrase ?

Comment: thats a bummer..i've been trying for days now to somehow know when the execv invocation has ended by putting a flag raise on a code that appears right after the execv call...but it doesnt get there if I send it a signal...it's annoying

Comment: @user1432779 Perhaps you can explain the higher goal ?

Comment: I need my program to run another program(say firefox), and to know when the firefox died or crashed..running a daemon in the background or something like that takes CPU and I believe that there are better ways...

Comment: @user1432779 You're looking for `SIGCHLD` in the parent :-) I [answered a similar question just the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320159/c-exit-status-of-a-program-running-in-background/13320167#13320167).

Comment: I can't use that because 1. a loop is busy-waiting on something 2. The parent has to do stuff , it can't just wait until the child dies :-(

Comment: @user1432779 It's not a busy wait. You put that **in the signal handler for `SIGCHLD`**.

Comment: Do read under what circumstances `SIGCHLD` is sent to whom, and you'll going to be enlightened ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As *Cnucitar* answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330279/841108), you can only change signal handler from inside the process.

If you wanted to make a signal handler inside firefox, you could patch it, perhaps thru a plugin. But I am sure that would be a bad idea.