# Open a programm and know if it is open

Tags: c++, windows, process

I want to write a program in C++ that can open a .exe program and I want to know when it's close by the user. I know that I can open a program by this code:

```
system ("start C:\\AAA.exe");
```

However I don't know how can I check if the program closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591342/c-how-to-determine-if-a-windows-process-is-running

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c - exit status of a program running in background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320159/c-exit-status-of-a-program-running-in-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `system ("C:\AAA.exe");` you can block until process AAA.exe finished.

If it is not acceptable, you can call `system ("C:\AAA.exe");` in separate thread, and check is it finished or not.

```
#include <thread>


void threadRoutine()
{
    ::system("C:\AAA.exe");
}

int main()
{
    std::thread systemCall(threadRoutine);
    //do some work here
    systemCall.join();
    //you are sure that AAA.exe is finished
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

On Windows if you use `CreateProcess()` instead of `system()` to start a new process. Simplified code:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
CreateProcess(..., &processInformation);
```

In `PPROCESS_INFORMATION` you find its handle. With its handle you can wait it's terminated (to mimic how `system()` works):

```
WaitForSingleObject(processInformation.hProcess, INFINITE);
```

Or periodically check its status getting its exit code (if any, see also [How to determine if a Windows Process is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1591342/1207195)) if your code has to run together with child process:

```
DWORD exitCode;
BOOL isActive = STILL_ACTIVE == GetExitCodeProcess(processInformation.hProcess, &exitCode);
```

Don't forget to close handle (even if process already terminated):

```
CloseHandle(processInformation.hProcess);
```

Note that with that code you don't know the reason process terminated. It may be because user closed its window, because it terminated by itself or because it crashed. For a GUI application you can hook its main window messages looking for `WM_CLOSE` (to detect user actions), `WM_QUIT` (application did it) and attaching an handler with `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter()` (to detect unhandled errors). It's not 100% reliable but it may be material for another question...